# How to connect and create a webpage that performs CRUD functionality to sitecore 9.3 using ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore-mvc

How can I connect and create a webpage that performs CRUD functionality to sitecore 9.3 using ASP.net MVC that are editable on content editor.

I tried to search videos and read documents on how but nothing seems to match on what I need.

Comment: If you are looking for a tutorial from a to b, StackOverflow may not be the right place...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.